# Як розуміти вислів "ходити "такою" "

Tags: різниця-між-словами

Що означає вираз "вона ходила "такою"? Даний вислів поширений серед старожилів одного із сіл Луцького району. І з чим могло бути пов'язане його виникнення?

Comment: На жаль, ми не можемо дізнатися мотивацію людей невизначених осіб, мешканців невизначеного населеного пункту. Для того, щоб можна було обʼєктивно відповісти на запитання, нам потрібен контекст, в якому ці особи використовують це слово.

Comment: У своєму мовленні використовувала моя бабуся(Луцький район, с. Лище, Волинь, якщо це допоможе). А контекст простий: "Вона ходить "такою". Це створювало ареол повної таємничості, ніби вони знають щось таке секретне, чого не можна знати іншим.

Answer (score 2):

«[Такою (в такім ділі) бути](http://stalivyrazy.org.ua/everyfile2.php?transfer=folders/b/beremennaja.html)» — один із евфемізмів на позначення вагітності. Хоча я не впевнений, що в даному випадку мається на увазі саме це.